# How to adjust the frame of right accessor to top right in MapView annotation?

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I want to add the right accessor image(cross image) to the top right corner as shown in the image below, but i am not able to get the code for it:
I am using the following code but its not giving me what i need.I need the cross button at the place shown in the image below.

```
annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];

       UIImage *listImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Close_normal.png"];
       UIButton *listButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

       // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
      // listButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,56,68);

       CGRect listButtonFrame = listButton.frame;


    listButtonFrame.size = listImage.size;
       listButton.frame = listButtonFrame;

       [listButton setImage:listImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = listButton;
```

[image]

And then also what i have to do is when i click on the cross button it should close the info pop up and remove the annotation

```
- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
 {
if( // left accessor is clicked then execute this code)  // what should i write here
 {
 SiteAnnotation *site = (SiteAnnotation *)view.annotation;
  if(site.category == -1) {
   if(addressAnnotation) {
       [mapView removeAnnotation:addressAnnotation];
AddViewController *vc = [[[AddViewController alloc]        initWithCoordinate:addressAnnotation.coordinate] autorelease];


   [self.delegate pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

   }
 }
        else {
             [self showSiteDetails:site.identifier];
             }
}
 else if (// if right accessor cross image is clicked)
{
  // Then here the code to dismiss the pop up and annotation pin on map

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this code:

use tags in the above method and control tag to get that tag working below..

```
 annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView.tag=1;
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag=2;



- (void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mv annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    SiteAnnotation *site = (SiteAnnotation *)view.annotation;


    // Left Accessory Button Tapped

    if(site.category == -1) {


        if ([control tag] == 1) {


            if(addressAnnotation) {

so on...
}
```

next try

```
else if ([control tag] == 2) {

            // "Right Accessory Button Tapped


            UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Touch and hold the pin icon to drag it around." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
            [alert1 show];
            [alert1 release];
        }
```

then in the method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{

 UIAlertView *alert_pin = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"cancel button click it " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

                [alert_pin show];
                [alert_pin release];

                [mapView removeAnnotation:addressAnnotation];
                [addressAnnotation release];
                addressAnnotation = nil;

            }
```

use alert and ask user to dismiss it or not rather using direct dismiss button on callout only.